# aurelia child route with "settings" parameter

Tags: router, aurelia

I would need to have some *settings* added to a child route using the aurelia router.

If I add the *settings* parameter to a main route, when the navigation pipeline goes through the *authorize step*, I can retrieve the settings using the *navigationInstruction.config.settings* property.

When navigating to a child route, the *authorizeStep* gets the route information of the main route with its *settings* and some information about the child route but no settings...

For instance:
if I have the following main route defined in *app.ts*

```
{name: 'user', settings: {bla: 'user'}...}
```

and the following child route defined in user.ts:

```
{name: 'useredit', settings: {bla: 'edit'}...}
```

Whether I navigate to the *user* or *useredit* route, I always get the following settings object : *{bla: 'user'}* as the navigation instruction is related to the main route.

How could I get the *{bla: 'edit'}* settings information when navigating to *edit*?

I sure hope the answer won't just be "child routes cannot have settings"... :)

thanks!

Comment: By calling `navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()`, you should get 2 instructions. The first is related to the main route, and the second to the child route, which contains contains the `settings: {bla: 'edit'}`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: GREAT! I didn't know about that function, it totally solves my problem! If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()`, you should get 2 instructions. The first is related to the main route, and the second to the child route, which contains contains the settings: `{bla: 'edit'}`. For instance:

```
class AuthorizeStep {
  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    // all the instructions here!
    let instructions = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions();
    // ... do something
    return next();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!